# Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseAuth' even after adding all the required dependencies

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have added all the required dependencies as per the docs and when I am trying to use the FirebaseAuth variable it shows **Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseAuth'**.
I have imported the required packages too.
I have added these dependencies in build.gradle(app) pls check-
**build.gradle (app) code -**

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
}
```

I am adding code of other gradle files just in case it might be the reason for error-
**build.gradle (project) code-**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}

//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle code-**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
//dependencyResolutionManagement {
//    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
//    }
//}

rootProject.name = "PUCabz"
include ':app'
```

When I tried to run the application it shows this error in log cat-
`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

Comment: Doesn't seem any problem here,, can you `invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: Have added the corresponding import? Can you show that to us? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: `package com.example.pucabz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class DriverLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button mLogin, mRegistration;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;`
See @AlexMamo the above code is what I have written. Still shows error

Comment: Already done that @SohaibAhmed 
the problem presist

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency and try if it works or not

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0'
```

Comment: Nope I had already tried this, I tried it again issue is still there.
when I tried to run the application it shows this error in log cat-
`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
`

Comment: The problem is solved when I commented out this dependency 
```//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1' ```
Do you know why this dependency was causing problems?

Comment: Actually, I did not need that ever, need to research for that, anyways. I'm happy it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Mine was resolved by adding the necessary dependencies through firebase assistant menu in the right side of android studio. You can remove all the related firebase authentication dependencies first.

[image]
[image]

After doing that, `FirebaseAuth` is found!